# Adding search function

Tags: website-design, forms, gui-design, interaction-design, search

I have a web application that is built around search. On the homepage, users are able to search for their desired product using a textbox and dropdown, then they get the results page, displayed below.

Is there a better way I can include search functionality on the results page without having to necessarily having the same set of text boxes at the top of the results page.

I looked at how Google have laid out theirs, they do not have the menu to the right like I have, so it's cleaner to have the search bar in front of the logo, and still have white space to the right.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write "without having to necessarily having the same ..."

I'd always include the same set of controls to search on the results page, including the user input (text field value, drop-down selection, segmented button state), for two reasons:

- If the search does not turn up the results the user was looking for (e.g., no results at all due to typo, or too many results due to unspecific search), it is important to show the user the inputs which have lead to the results. Oftentimes, the search box is available but cleared on the results page, and I have no chance at all to determine whether there are no results due to a typo or just no results. In the other case, if there are too many results, it is easy to edit or add search term for more specific results only if the search controls are on the results page (with the user input).
- Secondly, I'd keep the style and place of the  search controls (text field, segmented button) as much as possible. This will help the user to recognize that these are the values she entered previously. Any change in presentation might cause questions as to the why and how of the change. This might not be possible entirely because the page search starts may have a different layout as it has other content as well, but I try to keep it as similar as possible.

That said, I cannot quite interpret your sketch - I don't see any textbox to enter search terms, and I can't relate your statement "search for their desired product" with the timeline. By "menu to the right", do you mean the segmented button "Apps|Games|Movies|..." in your sketch? I interpreted that as a category selection for the search results.